# Right homotopy relation on the projective model structure of chain complexes

Tags: model-categories

In Mark Hovey's book $\textit{Model Categories}$ it is said that in the projective model structure of chain complexes, the right homotopy relation is precisely the
chain homotopy relation. However, I've found the following counter example:

Suppose $\mathbb{Q}$ is the rational numbers, and $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$.
Define $A$ to be the complex with $A_n=R$ for any $n$, and the differential $d$ is given by the multiplication by $x$. Define $f$ to be the identity map on $A$ and $g$ to be the zero map on $A$. We deduce that:

i) $f$ and $g$ are not chain homotopic.

This is because that if there exists maps $s_n:R\to R$ such that $ds_n+s_{n-1}d=f-g$, suppose $s_n(1)=a+bx$, then $s_{n-1}(x)=1-ax$, but this cannot be true since $s_{n-1}$ must be a $R$-module homomorphism and must maps $x$ to a multiple of $x$.

ii) $f$ and $g$ are right homotopic.

This is because $A$ is acyclic and $A\xrightarrow{(\mathrm{id},\mathrm{id})} A\oplus A\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}}A\oplus A$ gives a path object of $A$,
and $A\xrightarrow{(\mathrm{id},0)}A\oplus A\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}}A\oplus A$ yields the homotopy.

Is my counter example correct?

Comment: most likely yes, however, you have the problem that your object is not cofibrant, hence your Example might work out as a counterexample if you use the full category, however, for defining the homotopy category, you first need to take a cofibrant replacement. (otherwise you also can't guarantee that right homotopy is an equivalence). Hence it is a counterexample, but a counterexample with no effect, and especially outside of the objects you are actually conisdering